# How can i create a namespace in docker ENTRYPOINT?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, namespaces, linux-namespaces

I'm tryin to create a linux-namespace using `unshare` command in my docker

**What i want to do:**
I want to create a namespace using `unshare` command in background mode in my docker container once it's ready
I can do this by using commands manualy from inside the container like this:

```
unshare -rum & UNSHARE_NS_PID=$! # I use it's PID for other purposes later
```

Code above gives me desired result, it looks like this:

```
$ lsns
NS         TYPE   NPROCS PID USER COMMAND
4026531834 time        4   1 root /bin/sh -c /bin/bash bash
4026531837 user        3   1 root /bin/sh -c /bin/bash bash
4026532775 mnt         3   1 root /bin/sh -c /bin/bash bash
4026532776 uts         3   1 root /bin/sh -c /bin/bash bash
4026532777 ipc         4   1 root /bin/sh -c /bin/bash bash
4026532778 pid         4   1 root /bin/sh -c /bin/bash bash
4026532779 net         4   1 root /bin/sh -c /bin/bash bash
4026532891 cgroup      4   1 root /bin/sh -c /bin/bash bash
4026532892 user        1  11 root -sh
4026532893 mnt         1  11 root -sh
4026532894 uts         1  11 root -sh
```

**What's the problem:**
I'm using docker with docker-compose, and currently i tried running `unshare` command in ENTRYPOINT section of my Dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash && unshare -rum &
```

However, it seems to work, but won't let me enter the container for some reason. I've tried different variations, but still no luck

Is there a way to perform such a thing?

Comment: I'm not totally clear what you're trying to do here: normally a container only runs one process, and the Docker runtime itself manages cgroup namespaces.  What is the main process in the container, and why does that process need to manage namespaces?  Your output shows several processes, could these run separately, one to a container (and therefore each in a separate namespace)?